# API spec converter using golang

Tags: json, go, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

My task is to convert xml to OpenAPI spec (Swagger 2.0). I found a node package (https://github.com/LucyBot-Inc/api-spec-converter) that does it but I want a similar package in golang. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way for it by using API transformer (https://apimatic.io) It is providing APU for conversion between all different API specs. Hope this helps.